# Testing Angularjs locators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

Kind of getting desperate here.
I have a legacy testsuite using AngularJS (5.4.1) driven by Node 8.12.0.
I want to debug some tests but it seems impossible.

Control flow is enabled in the tests, so I followed the docs on [the protractor website](https://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging). Sadly, it does not work.
browser.pause() just get skipped and using browser.debugger() is deprecated from Node 8.

I decided to disable the control flow but I ran into another problem.
We go to a login page before accessing the application, and the angular debugger does not like that. When accessing the non-angular page, the debugger just quits, stating that angular is not defined.

I then turned to Google to see if there are any Chrome extensions that enable me to use the dev tools to test the locators, but to no avail.

Would be great if I can get the debugger working.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do I get the debugger working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a setup for IntelliJ

*(working directory is example)*
[image: IntelliJ]